# Google App maker date filtering

Tags: google-app-maker

In App maker table view i have a date field called "topic" , we want this column to be filtered using a drop down. The drop down options consists of already entered topic values. We populated the values in drop down, on value edit event we filtered the data source to the selected value, but the filter is not working. Can anyone suggest how to filter date values from a datasource.

Comment: Do you reload datasource after filter change(`app.datasources.MyDatasource.load()`)?

Comment: We want the filter to work on date field, How to pass filter value for date field.

Comment: use binding: `@datasources.MyDatasources.query.filters.MyField._FilterYouNeed`, then `onValueChange` you need to reload datasource.

Comment: I used this code in the `onValueEdit` event:
`widget.datasource.query.filters.DateField._lessThanOrEquals = newValue;
widget.datasource.load();`